# LSZ Reduction formula: Peskin and Schroeder

Tags: quantum-field-theory, correlation-functions, regularization

On page 224 of P&S, they have the following expression (7.36),

[image]

The integral over $d^3q$ gives us all the $q \to p$, then the integral over $dx^0$ is computed. The RHS given matches when only the $x^0 = T_+$ term of the integral is kept,  **what happens to the $x^0=\infty  $ term?**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think I can answer your question. Some complex analysis is used in order to derive the above-mentioned result. Starting with the RHS expression,

$$\sum_{\lambda}\int_{T_+}^{\infty}dx^0\int\frac{d^3q}{(2\pi)^3}
\frac{1}{2E_q(\lambda)}
e^{i(p^0-q^0+i\epsilon)x^0}\langle\Omega|\phi(0)|\lambda_0\rangle
(2\pi)^3\delta^3(\textbf{p}-\textbf{q})
\\\times\langle\lambda_{\textbf{q}}|T\{\phi(z_1)...\}|\Omega\rangle=\\
\sum_{\lambda}\int_{T_+}^{\infty}dx^0\int\frac{d^3q}{(2\pi)^3}
\frac{1}{2E_q(\lambda)}
\bigg[\frac{e^{i(p^0-q^0+i\epsilon)x^0}}{i(p^0-q^0+i\epsilon)}\bigg]_{T_+}^{\infty}
\\\langle\Omega|\phi(0)|\lambda_0\rangle
(2\pi)^3\delta^3(\textbf{p}-\textbf{q})
\times\langle\lambda_{\textbf{q}}|T\{\phi(z_1)...\}|\Omega\rangle$$
from which one only needs to consider the term in the brackets, namely
$$\frac{e^{i(p^0-q^0+i\epsilon)x^0}}{i(p^0-q^0+i\epsilon)}
\Bigg|_{T_+}^{\infty}=
-i\lim_{x^0\to\infty}
\frac{e^{i(p^0-q^0+i\epsilon)x^0}}{(p^0-q^0+i\epsilon)}
+i\frac{e^{i(p^0-q^0+i\epsilon)T_+}}{(p^0-q^0+i\epsilon)}$$
The last term is the term you are looking for, see LHS of Eq. (7.36) in P&S. The first term vanishes, since
$$-i\lim_{x^0\to\infty}
\frac{e^{i(p^0-q^0+i\epsilon)x^0}}{(p^0-q^0+i\epsilon)}=
-\frac{i}{(p^0-q^0+i\epsilon)}
\lim_{x^0\to\infty}e^{i(p^0-q^0)x^0}
\lim_{x^0\to\infty}e^{-\epsilon x^0}$$
This result is obviously zero, since the second limit vanishes, whereas the first one rapidly oscillates.

I hope this helps.